# Sentry - summary email feature

Tags: python, sentry

We currently have [sentry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentry) installed, but it doesn't really fit our needs. We have a lot of clients and whenever something is wrong on the clients, sentry sends one email per issue per client (because sentry is unable detect the issues being the same).

I couldn't find it, but is sentry capable of sending summary messages every X minutes instead? If not, what would be a good alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sentry doesn't currently provide digests, and in all honesty you will lose almost all of the power of a tool like it if the aggregation isn't functioning.

I would recommend [opening a ticket](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/new) describing the kinds of events that aren't aggregating, as there are ways to fix it, and it's generally not very complicated.